# Использование Google Speech API

Tags: php

Есть код

```
$file_to_upload = array('myfile'=>'@333.flac');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?xjerr=1&client=chromium&lang=ru-RU");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: audio/x-flac; rate=16000'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, file_get_contents('hhh.FLAC'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

var_dump($result); // возвращает bool(false)
```

Как сделать чтобы работало?

Comment: @opa4ki, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: Дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку на `hhh.FLAC`, чтобы можно было скачать.

Answer (score 4):

Еще актуально?

```
....
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch)); 
echo "\n\ncURL error number:" .curl_errno($ch); 
echo "\n\ncURL error:" . curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Скорее всего, проблема с сертификатом. Нужен `curl-ca-bundle.crt` и прописать к нему путь:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'c:/php/cert/curl-ca-bundle.crt');
```

Answer (score 1):

Очень актуально. Никогда не поздно поделиться тем что ты знаешь. Такая же проблема, скачал прописал путь. Отправляет файл даже назад приходить. Но только не приходит самое важное, текст и коэффициент.

```
$file_to_upload =    array('myfile'=>'n.flac');

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?xjerr=1&client=chromium&lang=ru-RU"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'Y:/home/localhost/www/flac/curl-ca-bundle.crt'); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: audio/x-flac; rate=16000")); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $file_to_upload); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); $result=curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$json_array = json_decode($result, true); 
$voice_cmd = $json_array["hypotheses"][0]["utterance"];
```

Выдает string(71) "{"status":5,"id":"341ec47eac0a66d36b98319d6c7b57ae-1","hypotheses":[]} "

Comment: status = 5 — запись не распознана. Работайте над качеством файла.

Comment: Качество файла отличное. Брал пример с хабра http://habrahabr.ru/post/117234/
Файл распознается.

Исправил как написано здесь 
http://mikepultz.com/2011/03/accessing-google-speech-api-chrome-11/comment-page-2/#comment-1047
В частности вставил  
$file = 'hello.flac';
$audio = "";
$file=fopen("hello.flac","r");
while(!feof($file)) {
$audio .= fgets($file). "”;
}
fclose($file);
И работает. Только очень долго из-за этого обрабатывает. 
Прикол в том, что у этого чувака, так как он написал не работает. А работает, как описано здесь. То есть сразу вставить $file, вместо $audio.

Comment: Здесь такая же проблемма http://forum.foxclub.ru/read.php?29,532001

Comment: Как написал автор темы
file_get_contents('hhh.FLAC')
эта функция заменяет те строки кода которые я выложил выше. Невнимательность.

Comment: у меня работает и с file_get_contents и этим сниппетом. файл сам пишу с микрофона, правда rate у меня 44,1кГц, а не 16к... вот если указать не тот rate, то тоже будет 5й статус. в общем да, надо оттестить на идеальном файле, получить положительный результат, дальше с другими файлами работать.

Comment: Читал что гугл не работает с файлом <44.1. Автор той статьи бы удивился. Когда я указал другой rate мне не прислал 5-й статус. А просто прислал ерунду.
Еще бы хотелось что бы php файл обрабатывал быстрее. файл длинной в 35 секунд, он обрабатывает за 55 секунд. на C# за 13 секунд.
Yura Ivanov Покажите как вы реализовали запись с микрофона

Comment: запись с микрофона идет с помощью [jRecorder](http://www.sajithmr.me/jrecorder-jquery) через swf'ку, берется дефолтный битрейт для винды, там как раз 44,1кГц. на сервере конверчу в [flac](http://flac.sourceforge.net/) И если для такого файла указать не тот битрейт, то выдает 5 статус.
Про время ничего не скажу, для команд или поиска, имхо, достаточно 3-5 секундных файлов, длинные фразы не проверял...